# Is Bluetooth battery information readable in Windows on Boot Camp?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, mouse

Is there any way to see the battery level of a Bluetooth device (e.g. magic mouse) in Windows with Boot Camp?

Answer (score 1):

There is an application for Windows called "Bluetooth Battery Monitor." It is in beta right now, but I use it for my Ghostek SoDrop 2.0 headphones, and it works well.

You can download the beta at: https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/

I don't think that BootCamp *per se* would make a difference as to whether the Windows program would work or not, or any program at all, for that matter.

Answer (score -6):

Our software [Magic Utilities](https://magicutilities.net) can read the battery state of all Apple Bluetooth devices.

Besides this, we offer much better multi-touch and keyboard support than BootCamp and run on any Windows computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please note that whenever you link to your own website, you need to state to explicitly; see [this Help Center article](/help/promotion). Even after the edit, it's still a very promotional post; consider [edit]ing your answer to include some actual information about your product instead of simply claiming your offer much better support; everybody writes that about their own product.